# $scope.$watch value wrapped in in promise $q.when(value)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angular-services

In my app I have a service that asynchronously returns cached value:

```
    .service('StateService', [
        '$q',
        function ($q) {
            var value;
            // ...
            // ...
            function getValue() {
                return $q.when(value);
            }
            // ...
            // ...
            return {
                getValue: getValue
                // ...
                // ...
            };
        }
    ]);
```

Static variable "value" is updated via setter in the same service.
It is a requirement to have getter `getValue()` that works asynchronously - the idea is to implement an id cache in the future.

In the main controller I need to `$watch` changes to `StateService.getValue()` and update scope with new `value` if it was changed.

**Is there a possibility to `$watch` promises (that are not actually a resource calls, but just a static value wrapped in a promise) with `$scope.$watch`?**

*Maybe by unwrapping them in every digest and comparing old a new value?*

Comment: An alternative would be to raise an event whenever the cache changes and have your controllers listen for this event as opposed to watching the cache?

Comment: Please, show how this is supposed to be used, there's not enough information. There's no reason for getValue to be a promise. If it is should be asyncronous, please, show that. It seems that you're trying to use promises for a thing they were never intended for. Consider using observables (e.g. RxJS) instead.

Comment: Does your asynchronous API execute its callback once or multiple times? Promises are containers for **one-time** values that are returned in the future. Watchers execute their callbacks multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not possible, the best option is to do the $watch in the $scope in the q is storing the value of your service